# Find max/min of $f(x,y,z)$ on closed unit ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$f(x,y,z) = 3x - 2y + z$

Let $B$ be a closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R^3}$, find the max/min of f on $B$.

We first need to observe

$(a)$ the behavior of $f$ in $B^0$

$(b)$ the behavior of $f$ on $\partial B$

Then we can find the $\max_B f$ and $\min_B f$.

I am confused as to how to do this. I think that since this is a smooth function, we know it takes its maximum value on $B$ and the point where the maximum occurs will solve the Lagrange Multiplier equation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For
$$\vec a = (3, - 2,1),\vec b = \frac{1}{{\left\| {\vec a} \right\|}}\vec a$$
is given:
$$f(\vec x) = \vec a \cdot \vec x$$
and constraint condition
$$g(\vec x) = {\left\| {\vec x} \right\|^2} - {R^2}$$
We build the Lagrange function:
$$L(\vec x,\lambda ) = f(\vec x) + \lambda  \cdot g(\vec x)$$
and calculate:
$${\nabla L = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {2\lambda  \cdot \vec x + \vec a} \\ 
  {{{\left\| {\vec x} \right\|}^2} - {R^2}} 
\end{array}} \right) = \vec 0}$$
That means
$$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {2\lambda  \cdot \vec x + \vec a = \vec 0} \\ 
  {{{\left\| {\vec x} \right\|}^2} - {R^2} = 0} 
\end{array}$$
Solution is not hard to find:
$$\lambda  =  - \frac{1}{{2 \cdot R}}\left\| {\vec a} \right\|,{{\vec x}_{\max }} = R\vec b,{{\vec x}_{\min }} =  - R\vec b$$
And we have:
$$f({{\vec x}_{\max }}) = R\left\| {\vec a} \right\|,f({{\vec x}_{\min }}) =  - R\left\| {\vec a} \right\|$$
With $$R \geqslant 0$$ one can study different cases.